# Error while trying to import data for wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, import, wordpress-theming, themes

I just activated this theme on WordPress known as "Bosa Consulting Demo", and I am having trouble trying to import it. I am getting this message, anyone can help?

Thank you

[image: Screenshot of image]

Comment: Have you verified that the plugin that is listed in the error message has been activated in your WordPress installation? I think the missing file is the problem.

Comment: Install the mentioned plugins before you do that. Else contact theme support: https://bosathemes.com/contact-us/ It's a premium theme.